# jqGrid: No records to view

Tags: jqgrid

I cant get jqGrid to show any records, my javascript:

```
jq.getScript("/js/grid.locale-en.js", function(){
    jq.getScript("/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js", function(){
        jq(".normalTable").jqGrid({
            url:'/xml/results.xml',
            mtype: "GET",
            datatype: "xml",
            colNames: ['Instrument', 'ExpValue', 'BuyerPayout','SellerPayout'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'Instrument', index: 'Instrument', width: 55, xmlmap: "Instrument" },
                { name: 'ExpValue', index: 'ExpValue', width: 80, xmlmap: "ExpValue" },
                { name: 'BuyerPayout', index: 'BuyerPayout', width: 80, xmlmap: "BuyerPayout" },
                { name: 'SellerPayout', index: 'SellerPayout', width: 80, xmlmap: "SellerPayout"}],
            pager: '#pager',
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            sortname: 'Instrument',
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            autoencode: true,
            xmlReader: {
               root:"TradingResults",
               row:"TradingResult"
            },
            width: '480'
        });
    });
});
```

My XML structure:

```
<TradingResults>
    <DateGroup date="2014-04-24">
        <TradingResult>
            <Instrument>xyz</Instrument>
            <ExpValue>94.65</ExpValue>
            <BuyerPayout>0</BuyerPayout>
            <SellerPayout>100</SellerPayout>
        </TradingResult>
        <TradingResult>
            <Instrument>xyz</Instrument>
            <ExpValue>94.659</ExpValue>
            <BuyerPayout>0</BuyerPayout>
            <SellerPayout>100</SellerPayout>
        </TradingResult>
    </DateGroup>
<TradingResults>
```

No errors in console.

Result:

[image: jqGrid empty grid]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you didn't set xml reader in your grid like.Grid need to expect xml

```
xmlReader: { repeatitems: false, root:"TradingResults",row:"TradingResult" }
```

and also set `xmlmap` for each column like

```
 { name: 'Instrument', index: 'Instrument', width: 55,xmlmap:"Instrument" },
```

Also did you include the DnR lib which is

```
<script src="grid/js/jqDnR.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

This one is important

**Update**: Since this answer is getting much attention, [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data) people may find additional information on jqgrid with xml data.

Comment: Thanks @janina, now the grid recognizes the number of rows, but now only displays an empty table: http://imgur.com/zuOzeZz

Comment: it made no difference, i still get an empty table. I also tried removing mType: "GET"

Comment: Solution in the end was:

xmlReader: {
 repeatitems: false,
 root:"TradingResults",
 row:"TradingResult"
}

 Please update your answer to include repeatitems: false

Comment: @Sam Thompson well done, u find the solution yourself